# some basic questions about topology- is this $[1,2]$ open under topology $\{\emptyset,X,[1,2]\}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

I remember the lecturer said when you ask if a set is open or closed you need to specify the topology, then the following example I am not sure if is it closed or open.

Let's say define a topology on $X=[0,\infty)$ and the topology is
$\{\emptyset,X,[1,2]\}$

I got the following questions:

**1**  is $[1,2]$ considered as open by definition? if so, then

**2** $[0,1)\cup(2,\infty)$ considered as closed, what about $[0,1)$? closed or Neither? I love to think like the finite union of closed is closed, even though I know that the finite union of neither open nor closed sets could be closed, but that is for the usual topology.

Thank you for clearing my mind about these two questions.

---

**Extra edited**

As I retrive this post I have another mind hope you guys may help me to clear up.

I agree that $[0,1)$ cannot construct by finite intersection nor arbitrary union. But if I look another way by arguing evey points in $[0,1)$ equipped with $\epsilon$-radius ball still lay in $[0,1)$.

1. Here is what my confusion come in : the point at $0$ with $\epsilon$-radius ball do not fully lay in $[0,1)$ becasue left hand side of the ball do not lay in $[0,1)$, so $[0,1)$ is not open.
2. However my another argument goes:  when centered at $0$, there is no left hand side of $\epsilon$-radius ball, beacuse we only defined on $[0,\infty)$, so it is open. (I personally incline to this), why is this argument incorrect.

Comment: yes, an element of a topology is open, by definition; a set is closed if its complement is open

Comment: Note: $\epsilon$-radius balls have nothing to do with this topology.  So your "extra" part is no good.

Comment: @GEdgar isn't $\epsilon$-radius ball of arbitrary $p\in [0,1)$ fully contained in the set defined the such set is open

Comment: As I said, $\epsilon$-radius balls have nothing to do with this topology.  They are used to define the usual topology.  Yes, $[0,1)$ is open for the usual topology of $[0,+\infty)$.  But so what?  We are not asked about that topology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question: Yes, $[1,2]$ is open by definition.

For the second one: $[0,1) \cup (2,\infty)$ is closed because its complement is $[1,2]$.
See that $[0,1)$ isn't open, because it can't be constructed with finite intersections nor arbitrary unions of the sets in your topology. On the other hand, $[0,1)^c=[1,\infty)$ isn't open either, by the same reason, so $[0,1)$ is neither open nor closed.

Comment: You should take the complement in $X$, not in $\mathbb R$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner: Thanks! My mistake.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I just re-edit the post and leave some question, thank you for your help.

Comment: @BrianBritosSimmari I just re-edit the post and leave some question, thank you for your help.